# Need a sql query for following scenarioa

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
Car      Owner

'honda','nepolian'
'benz','nepolian'
'nissan','nepolian'
'lexus','sivaji'
'honda','sivaji'
'benz','sivaji'
'nissan','sivaji'
'landrover','kumar'
'kiamotors','kumar'
'honda','kumar'
'ferrari','vivek'
'suziki','vivek'
```

I wanted to select the owner who has all the car which is own by nepolian?

Please help me to solve this!

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: what you want isnt clear ! try to edit your question and post your database schema ! and precise what you want ! "owner who has all the car which is own by nepolian" is nepolian !

Comment: I want to find the owners who has all the cars which is owned by nepolian.

Comment: when you keep your table name secret, it makes it harder to talk about and harder to answer

Comment: Please post at least some example of SQL that you've tried to use. Stack Overflow is here to help but not to write your code from the scratch :)

Answer (score 1):

No idea why you would tag this both mysql and oracle, but here's how in mysql (untested):

```
select owner
from yourtable
where car in (select car from yourtable where owner='nepolian')
and owner <> 'nepolian'
group by owner
having group_concat(car order by car)=(select group_concat(car order by car) from yourtable where owner='nepolian');
```

If a person can have multiple of the same car and you don't want to require the same numbers of each car, change slightly:

```
having group_concat(distinct car order by car)=(select group_concat(distinct car order by car) from yourtable where owner='nepolian');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to say you want all of the cars from the `Cars` column with the owner from the `Owner` column equal to `nepolian`? Within one table?

Unless it's something else (more complicated, I would hope), you should be able to do so with just:

```
SELECT car
FROM *name of table*
WHERE owner = 'nepolian';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.owner from (
  select count(t1.car) as car_count, t1.owner from tableName t1
  join tableName t2 on t2.car = t1.car
  where t2.owner = 'nepolian' and t1.owner <> 'nepolian'
  group by t1.owner )
t where t.car_count = (
  select tmp.car_count from (
         select count(car) as car_count, owner from tableName
         where owner = 'nepolian' group by owner
  ) tmp
)
```

Maybe it help you! Execute in `mysql` is OK! If the sql above is feasible，and it is not very slow, please give me a message!